# Is it possible to copy the tab completion of a command for my linux function?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh, tab-completion

Let's say I have a bash shell function named **magic**. I want to define a tab completion function **_magic** which would allow **magic** to piggyback on the tab completion functions of any given command (if available). In other words, I want **magic** to be able to do something like this:

```
~ $ magic git ... <search for _git and use it if found>
~ $ magic cd ... <search for _cd and use it if found>
~ $ magic some-cmd ... <search for _some-cmd and use it if found>
```

I can't seem to find anything online that would help me achieve this using compgen, complete etc. Is this even possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe there is something useful in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537074/use-compgen-to-get-autocomplete-for-another-command-which-flag-to-use

Comment: See if running this in bash helps: `complete -F _command magic`

Answer (score 3):

There are many such (pseudo?) commands, that need this. e.g. `time`, `nice`, `strace` etc.
They all use the same command completion: `_command`. So, don't re-invent the wheel. :)

Try running this in your bash terminal, if this work:

```
complete -F _command magic
```

Comment: Hello anishsane, I am aware of complete -F. What I want is to dynamically switch the _command depend on the first argument to my "magic" function. Are you saying I should literally call "complete -F _command magic" in my _magic function?

Comment: No, there should not be any `_magic` function. Just try the command I gave.