# How can I get zsh to inherit the complete autocompletion?

Tags: zsh-completion

I have an little shell script (named "run") which redirects all output of a program to /dev/null:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
$@ &> /dev/null &
disown +
```

How can I say zsh that the whole autocompletion shall work for this?

I mean

```
$ run git com<TAB>
```

autocomplete to

```
$ run git commit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make that work by adding:

```
compdef _command run
```

to my .zshrc file.

I've based my answer on [this bash question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353719/is-it-possible-to-copy-the-tab-completion-of-a-command-for-my-linux-function) It was worth giving it a try with compdef - surprisingly it worked.
As I'm still zsh/autocompletion newbie I cannot explain the inner workings and you should probably go through the [documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html) or other sources to find more on the topic.