# Is it possible to make a bash script that delegates completion to another program?

Tags: bash, bash-completion, compgen

I'm trying to write a wrapper script around another program (e.g. `foo_wrapper` around `foo`), which simply overrides some flags on every call to `foo`. I want users to be able to interact with `foo_wrapper` and `foo` exactly the same way, including seeing the same bash completion output.

For example, `foo_wrapper.sh` should simply add `--my_flag` on every call to `foo`, but it's not enough to simply prepend or append flags to the argument list, it has to put them in the right location because of the way `foo` is implemented. So if the user calls `foo_wrapper bar baz`, I want it to map to `foo bar --my_flag baz`. This is why I assume I cannot simply use a bash alias.

This would be a simple script if I didn't need bash completion to work, but without bash completion this thing is not going to be nearly as useful. Can anyone help me figure out what to do here? I discovered the `compgen` builtin for bash, but I'm having trouble seeing how/if I can use it for this.

Comment: Is your real question how to implement bash completion for your wrapper? I would start with the bash completion for the thing you're wrapping, and just add your extra piece.

Comment: You don't want exactly the same completion output, though, right? `foo` completion will offer `--my_flag`, but you don't want to see that in the completion for `foo_wrapper`.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537074/use-compgen-to-get-autocomplete-for-another-command-which-flag-to-use/30541042